# Having trouble understanding op amp purpose

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, adc, bias, dc-offset

I came across an op amp circuit in a paper I am reading. The paper says it is supposed to be a 2.5 V dc offset, but I can't find a way to confirm that. I tried replicating it in LT Spice, but it doesn't seem to do the 2.5 V offset, instead just seems to randomly rescale values. I tried giving it to GPT and Bard, but they seem to think its just a weird amplifier. I tried the regular tools like, http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuLowkeisan.htm but I cant find a circuit that matches. If anyone can better explain what this circuit is doing to the incoming signal.

Some extra info, the bias voltage is +- 15 V. [image]

Comment: Please post a link to the paper.  I'd like to see what else it says that might need adjusting.

Comment: I wonder why they picked those resistor values. 2k, 20k and 120k would have given 2.500 V exactly.

Comment: The plus and minus signs on the LT1007 look MSPaint-ed.  Is this the original image?

Comment: I have a feeling he picked those values because they were the resistors that they had laying around. I did modify the image because the errata said to. It sounds like though that the errata was wrong and that the original image was correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Basic idea

The circuit (with swapped op-amp inputs) is actually a *2-input inverting summing amplifier* with a gain of -10 and an output offset voltage of 2.5 V. It is probably designed to convert a bipolar input voltage in the range (-0.25÷0.25) V to a unipolar output voltage in the range (5÷0) V applied to an ADC.

## Superposition principle

The circuit is a very good illustration of the superposition principle. Let's consider it.

**Vin = -0.25 V; Voff = 0 V (only Vin):** The circuit acts as an *inverting amplifier* with gain of -10 producing 2.5 V output voltage (Vout = 10.R2/R1 = 2.5 V). I have added R4 to compensate for a small voltage offset.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgw4B8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Vin = 0 V; Voff = -15 V (only Voff):** The circuit acts as another inverting amplifier producing 2.5 V output voltage (Vout = 15.R2/R3 = 2.5 V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9f38i.png)</sup>

**Vin = -0.25 V; Voff = -15 V (both):** The two voltages are superimposed (summed) at the output (Vout = 10.R2/R1 + 15.R2/R3  = 2.5 V + 2.5 V = 5 V); see the picture below.

## Exploration

### Manually...

Let's first see how the circuit acts for three typical values of Vin.

### Vin = -0.25 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9kIag.png)</sup>

### Vin = 0 V

This situation is the same as in the schematic 1.2 above; I have put it here for completeness.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0kzFD.png)</sup>

### Vin = 0.25 V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu6qg5.png)</sup>

Thus the unipolar ADC is made to act as bipolar.

### Automatically

Let's now see how the circuit acts for all possible values ​​of Vin (obtained by the *DC Sweep Simulation*).

[image: STEP 1]

Answer (score 5):

> *The paper says it is supposed to be a 2.5 V dc offset, but I can't
> find a way to confirm that.*

That's a comparator circuit with hysteresis. Notice that feedback (via the 15 kΩ resistor) returns to the non-inverting terminal and not the inverting terminal. In other words, it's not an amplifier: -

[image]

Try swapping the inverting and non-inverting terminals in LTSpice to see if it does produce 2.5 volts at the output but, without knowing what the voltage is on the left terminal of the 1.5 kΩ resistor, it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting the LT1007 labeling of IN+ and IN-, the standard inverting equation \$V_{out}=\frac{-R_f}{R_i}(-15)\$ will yields a Vout of approximately 2.47V, with the input to the 1.5k resistor at 0V.